# JSON shown as "undefined" with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, arduino

I'm a complete newbie, so maybe some answers have to be a bit explained.
I'm trying to make a small html page that contains a JSON string. The page is hosted by Arduino on my local network (tested and working). To retrieve info from the JSON string, I've followed a video tutorial of jQuery: [JSON AJAX jQuery tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ)

So, I adapt the sketch a little to my needs, but it finally bugs. In the console, I can see that I get the JSON, but in the page, the value is shown as "undefined".

Here is the code:

```
    $(function(){

    var $channels = $('#channels'); //store array

    $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://192.168.0.110/ajax_inputs',
     success: function(channels){
     $.each(channels, function(i, channel){ 
        $channels.append('<p>channel # '+ channel.canal +' name: '+               channel.name +'</p>')
    console.log(channels.canal)
            });
        },
    error: function() {
    alert('error loading data')

    }
    });


    });
```

and this is the JSON data:

```
    channels: [,…]
    0: {name: "NAME 0", status: 1, canal: 0, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 1, percentOut: 100}
    1: {name: "NAME 1", status: 0, canal: 1, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    2: {name: "NAME 2", status: 0, canal: 2, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    3: {name: "NAME 3", status: 0, canal: 3, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    4: {name: "NAME 4", status: 0, canal: 4, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    5: {name: "NAME 5", status: 0, canal: 5, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    6: {name: "NAME 6", status: 0, canal: 6, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    7: {name: "NAME 7", status: 0, canal: 7, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    8: {name: "NAME 8", status: 0, canal: 8, temperature: 0, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
    9: {name: "NAME 9", status: 0, canal: 9, temperature: -50, setPoint: 5, permission: 0, percentOut: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referring to the `channels` variable, which in your json is an object whof objects

See [this stripped down JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hLtfhn0/5/) showing two ways to access the json in the loop.

The loop is here:

```
$.each(channels, function(i, channel){ 
    console.log(channels[i].canal);
    console.log(channel.canal);
});
```

In the first output the top level array `channels` is queried using the loop iterator `i`.

In the second, the loop variable `channel` is queried, so the loop iterator is not required to see the value. For the record, it looks like your `append()` call does this and should work, it's just the console log that's wrong (easy mistake to make :-))

Your mistake was that you were querying the full array but without the iterator, effectively looking for this:

```
channels = { // note the curly brace for an object, which you need for text keys
    'canal': '' // your code looks for this, which doesn't exist
    0: {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: at first, It was only the append() function that I was using, and it display "undefine" on the page to. doing exactly the same thing from the tutorial, everything was ok until I try to acces object inside the json...